# PHP pack binary data format CHAR c++

Tags: php, c++, sockets, binary, pack

I need to rewrite c++ application to PHP and in c++ i have this structure of message is used in socket tcp/ip communication:

[image]

So to can send message in one TCP/IP connection in binary i use this code in PHP:

```
 $message = pack('N', 1431655765)                  //HEADER - uint32 ui32Synch1
    . pack('N', 2863311530)                           //HEADER - uint32 ui32Synch2
    . pack('n', 1)                                    //HEADER - uint16 ui16Version
    . pack('N', 1)                                    //HEADER - uint32 ui32Cmd;
    . pack('N', 44)                                   //HEADER - uint32 ui32BodySize
    . pack('a20', pack('c', "44436412"))              //BODY - char szLisence[20]
    . pack('a20', pack('c', "Test_Program"))          //BODY - char szApplName[20]
    . pack('I', 0);                                   //BODY - int  nRet

    echo "<br/> Correct Message - packed = " . $message . "<br/> strlen " . strlen($message);
```

Message before send in method socket_send()in PHP vs message in C++:
[image]

The message is almost equal, but i have problem with characters after "ªªªª", what i'm doing wrong?

**Notes:**
Byte order: Little-Endian
strlen($message) = 62, that is correct because is the size of message i need to send and the size is equal to 62 bytes in c++ and in documentation.

**UPDATE:**
After request in comments:

**PHP code:**
[image]

**C++ code:**

Button to call function to regist:

```
void CPMSifDlg::OnbtnReg() 
{
    SPMSifRegisterMsg *m_RegMsg;
    BYTE *pbytesSend;
    BYTE *pbytesReceive;

    m_RegMsg = new SPMSifRegisterMsg;

    UpdateData(TRUE);
    strcpy(m_RegMsg->szLicense, m_strLic);      //Build the data
    strcpy(m_RegMsg->szApplName, m_strAppl);
    m_RegMsg->nRet=0;
    SetHeader(&m_RegMsg->hdr1, CMD_REGISTER);

    pbytesSend = new BYTE[sizeof(SPMSifRegisterMsg)];
    memcpy(pbytesSend, m_RegMsg, sizeof(SPMSifRegisterMsg));     //copy m_RegMsg structure to pbytesStore

    pbytesReceive=TCPSend(pbytesSend, sizeof(SPMSifRegisterMsg));         //sends pbytesStore and receives the response

    m_RegMsg=(SPMSifRegisterMsg*)pbytesReceive;                     //copy response back to structure
    m_iRegRes=m_RegMsg->nRet;
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Function call to send message and receive response:

```
BYTE *CPMSifDlg::TCPSend(BYTE *pbytesStore, int size)
{
    BYTE *pbytes;
    BOOL bEmpty;
    int nRetVal, nRead;
    int nMsgSize;
    SPMSifHdr spHdr;

    //check endian
    if ( htonl(47) == 47 ) {
      // Big endian
    } else {
      // Little endian.
    }
    m_mySocket.Send((void*)pbytesStore, size);

    nRetVal = m_mySocket.Receive((void*)&spHdr, sizeof(SPMSifHdr), MSG_PEEK);

    if ((nRetVal >= sizeof(SPMSifHdr)) && (spHdr.ui32Synch1 == 0x55555555) && (spHdr.ui32Synch2 == 0xaaaaaaaa))
    {
        nMsgSize = spHdr.ui32BodySize + sizeof(SPMSifHdr);
        pbytes = new BYTE[nMsgSize];

        bEmpty = FALSE;
        nRead = 0;
        nRetVal = 0;
        while(!bEmpty)
        {
            nRetVal = m_mySocket.Receive(pbytes, nMsgSize);

            if (nRetVal > 0)
                nRead += nRetVal;

            if ((nRetVal <= 0) || (nRead == nMsgSize))
                bEmpty = TRUE;
            else if (nRead <= nMsgSize)
                pbytes += nRetVal;
        }

        if (nRead != nMsgSize)
            MessageBox("FAILED to Receive TCP message");
        else
            return pbytes;
    }
    return pbytesStore;
    }
```

**SOLVED:**

After some experiences i solve the situation doing only this:

```
  $message = pack('N', 1431655765)      //HEADER - uint32 ui32Synch1
. pack('N', 2863311530)                 //HEADER - uint32 ui32Synch1
. pack('v', 1)                          //HEADER - uint16 ui16Version
. pack('V', 1)                          //HEADER - uint32 ui32Cmd;
. pack('V', 44)                         //HEADER - uint32 ui32BodySize
. pack('a20', "44436412")               //BODY - char szLisence[20]
. pack('a20', "Test_Program")           //BODY - char szApplName[20]
. pack('I', 0);                         //BODY - int  nRet
```

Comment: It could be just different encoding in your browser and in C++ IDE which shows that as different chars.

Comment: Could be this, but when i send message with socket_send() the browser freeze until get time_out, how can debug this?

Comment: already add code of PHP and c++, i need rewrite this c++ app to php and this one example of function/communication i need to make with sockets tcp/ip.

Comment: There http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/282427-cdelphi-socket-tcpip-to-php-memcpymove-function-in-php/ i have more info about the problem.